# How can I suppress 301 redirects from the target with node-http-proxy?

Tags: javascript, node.js, redirect, proxy, node-http-proxy

When the target of the proxy issues a redirect (301 in this case), the proxy forwards that to the client. The client is then redirected to the actual domain and no longer using the proxy. Is there a way to prevent this redirection from affecting the client? I want the proxy to follow the redirect, but I don't want the client to leave the proxy while following this redirect.

Example case:

Assume I have a proxy running on `fake-proxy.example`. When setting the target to a server ip and then setting the host to a domain on that server, the proxy tries to connect via `http`. The domain is set up to redirect `http` traffic to `https` and issues a 301 redirect to the same domain with `https`. This redirect is sent back to the client, and the client leaves `fake-proxy.example` and goes to the actual domain (for the sake of this question, let's call it `real-domain.example`). My configuration:

```js
var options = {
    target: {
        host: '1.1.1.1'
    },
    headers: {
        host: 'real-domain.example'
    },
    autoRewrite: false,
    hostRewrite: false,
    protocalRewrite: false
};
```

I appreciate the help!

Comment: any luck with this?

Comment: I am fighting this too. I want it to be stable. With no redirects to real domains..

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit late, but a solution like the following one could help those that stumble on this post :

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var request = require('request');

var host = 'http://real-domain.example';

http.createServer(onRequest).listen(3080);

function onRequest(req, res) {
    var url_parts = url.parse(req.url);
    request({
        url: host + url_parts.pathname
    }).on('error', function(e) {
        res.end(e);
    }).pipe(res);
}
```

Of course, cookies and the like won't get preserved and you will likely lose some functionality I guess, but at least, it's *stable*, as in *you will not get redirected out of your proxy domain*.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else looking for this, [http-proxy-middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy-middleware#http-proxy-options) has a followRedirects option

```js
const express = require('express');
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

const app = express();

const url = 'http://target-server'

app.use(
  '/login',
  createProxyMiddleware({
    target: url,
    pathRewrite: {
      [`^/login`]: '',
    },
    followRedirects: true,
  })
);

// Start the Proxy
app.listen('localhost', 3000);
```